# long press and drag for UICollectionView multiple selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I am attempting to select multiple cells in a UICollectionView by long pressing on a cell, then dragging to other cells to select them.

I have successfuly been able to use a Pan Gesture Recognizer to locate the cell and call the method to select it:

```
- (void) didPanToSelectCells:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture{
    if (!_collectionView.selectionMode){
        [self.collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        return;
    }else{
        if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            [self.collectionView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [self.collectionView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        }else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
            CGPoint location = [panGesture locationInView:self.collectionView];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];

            if (![_collectionView.selectedIndexes containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]){
                [self.collectionView selectCell:[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath selected:YES];
            }
        }else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
            [self.collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            [self.collectionView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call:

```
[self.collectionView selectCell:[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath selected:YES];
```

Nothing happens!
I am able to call it in another method and it works **fine** but when called from the gesture recognizer **it does not do anything**.

I have added the following Gesture Recognizer Delegate Methods as well to no avail:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

And:

```
[gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

**Does anyone know of a way of properly doing this?**

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?